# Can we fetch QR codes from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, qr-code

I'm just little curious that is there any way to get all QR codes from html ?
Actually I've HTML but problem is I don't exact format of QR codes in HTML for example some might be like PNG or some like data:image/png;base64 or maybe some other way to show QR codes also I can't get it by image tags as it can be used as background as well and also in HTML there can be lots of other images as well in that HTML

So, just want to know is there anything which can track / detect QR codes from web page ?

Actually I needed it for my Chrome extension

Comment: Extensions don't have a magic API for this so you'll need to use the standard DOM methods or look for existing libraries.

Comment: Yes, its fine for JS as well but not able to find any similar library

Comment: A QR code is just an image, so it'll be hard to tell it apart from other images, IMO, unless you're going to start examining the contents of the image